# How to page reload after print my page?

Tags: javascript, jquery, printing

```js
function printdiv(printpage) {
    var headstr = "<html><head><title></title></head><body>";
    var footstr = "</body>";
    var elements = document.getElementsByClassName('hide-print-area');
    for (var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
        elements[i].style.display = 'none';
    }
    var newstr = document.all.item(printpage).innerHTML;
    var oldstr = document.body.innerHTML;
    document.body.innerHTML = headstr + newstr + footstr;
    window.print();
    document.body.innerHTML = oldstr;
    for (var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
        elements[i].style.display = 'block';
    }
    return false;
}
window.onafterprint = function() {
    //alert("Hello");
    window.location.reload(true);
};
```

```html
<html>
<head>
<title>Test Printing Page </title>
</head>
<body>
   <div id="printArea">
    <h2>Print Title</h2>
    <div>Desciption Here</div>
    <input class="hide-print-area" type="button" value="Print" onclick="printdiv('printArea')" />
   
   </div>
</body>
</html>
```

*Mozilla* browser page refreshed when I click on `cancel` button But while I am clicking on `ok` button page not refreshed.

*Chrome* nothing happen.

I have checked `onafterprint` event. This is calling everytime but page not refreshed. Please help me.

I want to page reload after print my page.

Comment: try window.location=''

Comment: replace `window.location.reload(true);` by `window.location='';`

Comment: @BadshahSahib `window.location='';` also not working

Comment: Is it necessary to reload your page ***only and exactly*** after the printing is done? I mean that once the printing command is sent, you can reload your page anyway. In almost cases the printing should succeed.

Comment: @KingKing yes this is necessary to reload page.

Answer (score 0):

The below work for **firefox** yes, for **chrome** no.Your page is reloading alright just that it didn't work in chrome.

```
 window.onafterprint = function() {
        window.location.reload(true);
    };
```

For **chrome onafterprint** doesn't work as there is no implementation of that so you need to **addListeners** to media queries one of the way is as mentioned below to acheive the same.

```
window.matchMedia('print').addListener(function (media) {

      if(media.matches){

      }
      else{
           window.location.reload(true);
            //location.reload();
      }
   });
}
```

Although I don't get what's the point of writing into html and then again reloading the page.

Please refer below link for working sample:

https://jsfiddle.net/f8fp9k0x/

Answer (score 0):

After  document.body.innerHTML = oldstr;
Add     window.location.reload(true);

Comment: Please don't post only code as an answer, but also provide an explanation of what your code does and how it solves the problem of the question. Answers with an explanation are usually more helpful and of better quality, and are more likely to attract upvotes

Answer (score 0):

use await async
it will work

```
$(document).on('click', '#print', async function() {
    var contents = $("#printsection").html();
    var frame1 = $('<iframe />');
    frame1[0].name = "frame1";
    frame1.css({
        "position": "absolute",
        "top": "-1000000px"
    });
    $("body").append(frame1);
    var frameDoc = frame1[0].contentWindow ? frame1[0].contentWindow : frame1[0].contentDocument.document ? frame1[0].contentDocument.document : frame1[0].contentDocument;
    frameDoc.document.open();
    //Create a new HTML document.
    frameDoc.document.write('<html><head><title>DIV Contents</title>');
    frameDoc.document.write('<style>@page {size: auto; margin: 0;height:auto;max-height:100%;}</style>');
    //Append the external CSS file.
    //Append the DIV contents.
    frameDoc.document.write(contents);
    frameDoc.document.write('</body></html>');
    frameDoc.document.close();
    await setTimeout(function() {
        window.frames["frame1"].focus();
        window.frames["frame1"].print();
        frame1.remove();
    }, 500);
    await setTimeout(function() {
        window.location.href = "";
    }, 1000);
});
```